Unable to sign in with Google using Firebase auth on Mobile website
I am able to sign in with Google using Firebase on desktop without issue using signInWithPopup. However, I am unable to do so on a mobile device. The internet told me to instead use signInWithRedirect. I have attempted to deploy and try it on my domain and I have tried it locally. I am able to get the redirect to work, but upon redirecting back to the site, it fails here.
AuthContext.tsx:
  const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Starting Google sign-in redirect...");
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Google sign in error:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Checking for redirect result on mount...");
    const handleRedirectResult = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await getRedirectResult(auth);
        if (result) {
          const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
          const token = credential?.accessToken;
          
          console.log("Redirect successful!");
          console.log("Access Token:", token);
          console.log("User:", result.user);
          // Check if email exists in user's account
          const isNewUser = !result.user.email || !(await result.user.getIdToken());
          console.log("Might be a new user:", isNewUser);
        } else {
          console.log("No redirect result found on mount");
        }
      } catch (error: any) {
        console.error("Error getting redirect result:", error);
        // Handle specific error cases
        console.error("Error Code:", error.code);
        console.error("Error Message:", error.message);
        console.error("Email:", error.email);
        console.error("Credential:", error.credential);
      }
    };

    handleRedirectResult();
  }, []);

Console Logs:

Checking for redirect result on mount...
result:  null
No redirect result found on mount

I am unsure what I am missing here.

Can you share a minimal, reproducible example perhaps on https://stackblitz.com/? It would be easier for us to debug that way given we have the exact code that you have,
